# How to download pdf with readable name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to download pdf with readable name?

I open a pdf in a new window and want to download it, but how can I get the name of this document instead of the generated id?

```
myRequest: (data) => {
   const contentType = data?.headers["content-type"]
   const blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: contentType })
   window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), "_blank")
},
```

***At the time of downloading, I want to receive the name of the document, and not its id, for example document-name.pdf***

[image]

[image]